# Reputation league and your position reported at the top of the list

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

In the last week the reputation league pages have changed: They used to show yourself at the top with your position, and they don't show that anymore.

Can we have it back, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No repro; this is working for me.

Are you logged in? Does the top of the http://stackexchange.com site have your name up there with "log out"?

If not, you may want to clear cookies and try again.

Comment: Ah I was logged in on all the sites and meta but this page requires to to login again

Comment: Actually it seems to depend on the [specific](http://i.imgur.com/Raphs.png) [site](http://i.imgur.com/YOKyL.png).