# Reputation League pages need pagination controls at the top to enhance UX

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, reputation-leagues, user-experience

It is standard UI practice to put pagination controls at the top and bottom of long lists.

The Reputation League pages are kind of frustrating because the pagination controls are only at the bottom. This means that for most people, you need to repeatedly scroll all the way down to change pages (no, pressing <kbd>End</kbd> is not a practical solution, only an equally frustrating work-around).

Comment: *"It is standard UI practice to put pagination controls at the top and bottom of long lists."* Someone should tell Google. They've been doing search wrong all these years!

Comment: No, they’ve just been doing interface wrong. Plenty of users have complained about the page links being at the bottom. To be fair though, the whole point is that Google returns the relevant page in the first few results, so most users are rarely even supposed to change pages (in which case, putting the pagination controls at the bottom is actually a bit of an ad for their search algorithm). That’s not how the RepLeagues work, so users will *frequently* need to change pages.

Comment: I thought that *was* how the rep leagues work. The users with the most rep are at the top of the list!

Comment: Yes, but how many people actually go to those pages to see the *top* users? Most people are more interested in seeing their *own* placement (and surrounding users; eg to see how close they are to moving up). In which case, they need to change pages until they find themselves.

Comment: @Synetech I know this doesn't address the question but you might try clicking on the "top n% [overall|year|quarter|month|week]" link next to your reputation on your summary profile page.

Comment: @ConradFrix, that’s how I get to the RepLeague page in the first place, but when you then click one of the other time-ranges (year, all-time, etc.), it starts from page one.

Comment: @Synetech  Also (and I didn't realize this before) there's a link that appears when you [hover over your name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d4gSp.png). This also brings you to [where you are](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pUy6c.png)

Comment: And now that link is gone. `:-|`

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, I was  sad to see it went away http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124075/what-happened-to-the-link-beside-each-user-which-appeared-on-hover-in-the-leag

Answer (score 1):

From the comments

> Yes, but how many people actually go to those pages to see the top
>   users? Most people are more interested in seeing their own placement
>   (and surrounding users; eg to see how close they are to moving up). In
>   which case, they need to change pages until they find themselves

Paging sucks when you're interested in a specific user no matter where you put the links. That's why (and this is news to me) there's a better to find where a user is in the list.

Just type in the user you want (unless its just yourself then you'll be at the top) and click the link that appears when you mouse over the user.

[image]

---

And There you are

[image]

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, the user’s block is [not always shown at the top](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100501/). (Besides, the `link` link is great for a specific user, but simply browsing through is still frustrating.)

Comment: I think that only happens when you have *not* earned rep in that time frame or you're already on the page that you're ranked on. For example for me that would be this page on the [all time superuser list](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/alltime/superuser/2008-08-01/42881?sort=reputationchange#42881) or the [current week](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser)

Comment: *> you're already on the page that you're ranked on* @Conrad, [that’s not it](http://i.imgur.com/Raphs.png).

Comment: *> I think that only happens when you have not earned rep in that time frame* That’s also not it because I have earned some rep on SO this week, yet the RepLeague week page doesn’t have my user block at the top.

Comment: @Synetech unfortunately i.imgur is blocked where I am so I can't see it. Also Are you sure you meant SO? Your [SO profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/119540/synetech?tab=reputation) says you haven't earned anything since 2/12.

Comment: The screenshot (can you see any screenshots on SE?), just shows my user block at the top as well as a few spots below it (#3), so it’s not that it doesn’t show if you are on that page (it just shows you twice). I didn’t look at the SO profile page, I just hovered over my name at the top of the page (I figured the items it shows were recent). I got a few points on Meta today, so I’ll check the RepLeague page for it tonight (after the updates) to verify your other point.

Comment: I can see stuff in i.stack.imgur.com but what you've described sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an [UserScript](https://stackapps.com/q/7242) for the request and posted in the Stack Apps.

Just a workaround to clone the pagination content and append to the userlist div details.

The UserScript as:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Leagues Top Pagination
// @namespace   http://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar
// @author      Arulkumar
// @description Moving the bottom pagination to the top of the user list in Stack Exchange Leagues
// @match       *://stackexchange.com/leagues/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
(function ($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {

    if($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').length > 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').first().remove();

    if($('#leagueUserList .pager').length > 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .pager').first().remove();

    if($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').length >= 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .league-container').first().css('border-top', '1px solid #F0F0F0');

    $('#leagueUserList')
      .prepend($('#leagueUserList .pager').clone())
      .prepend($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').clone());

  });
}(jQuery));
```

**The output will be:**

[image: Top pagination, if you doesn't have >200 reputation on the site]