# What happened to the `Link` beside each user which appeared on hover in the Leagues?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

In the Reputation Leagues redesign, what became of the `Link` which appeared beside each user on hover ([shown in a screenshot on this meta question from earlier in the week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/reputation-league-pages-need-pagination-controls-at-the-top-to-enhance-ux))?

Was it intentionally removed? If so, I would request it restored. It was really useful for seeing a user in context of the surrounding users.

#### Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, the link is still there, but never visible.[image]

#### Image lifted from [earlier Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/reputation-league-pages-need-pagination-controls-at-the-top-to-enhance-ux):

[image: Image of the link]

Comment: Well, the link's still there...just always hidden, huh.

Comment: @TimStone Indeed it is. Maybe this needs a `[bug]` tag too.

Comment: was this supposed to show up on hover or something?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes, it was supposed to appear on hover, and It's already been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was unintentionally broken when we upgraded from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.7.1. When using jQuery's `hover` function, we were checking for the `mouseover` event type instead of `mouseenter`. It's fixed now.